# Why is my mask in PS semi transparent?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask, selections

I am trying to remove part of an image, but each time I add a mask, that mask is always semi transparent. Opacity and Fill settings for the brush I am using are set to 100% and blending modes are set to normal.

I have never come across this before and I think I have tried everything. I don't know if this is a Photoshop problem or if there is a setting I should change. Any idea what is it?

[image: Semi transparent mask]

Comment: Are you sure, that color of mask fill is black (0,0,0)?

Comment: Thanks guys, I have changed HEX to #000000 and that sorted my problem.

Answer (score 2):

As sergeydyadyul suggests in the comments, please make sure that the colour you use to fill the black part of your mask is actually fully black. Not just CMYK 100%K black, a full `0,0,0` RGB black.

Especially with the colour picker, it's easy to accidentally select a very dark grey. Just drag the circle all the way beyond the edge of the picker to ensure a good black, or manually enter `#000000` in hex mode.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have changed HEX to #000000 and that sorted my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, if you work in CMYK, the black on your mask needs to be C100-M100-Y100-K100.

Sometimes the Hex black will not show you that transparency and will look alright on screen.

**But on plates or real printer proof**, you will see that the mask isn't totally opaque! So hex 000000 is alright for web projects I guess but use the C100-M100-Y100-K100 if you think you'll ever need that image for print though.

I personally use the CMYK registration black for all masks.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem since a day or two, it works for me to use the "levels" tool on the layermaks and set the whiteness higher.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no PS pro but I have left my mask heavily desaturated while working on it and then forgetting to turn it back to 100%. I have the same issue when I forget to change it back.